# React Native in iOS: load wasm cause Out of executable memory in function at index error

Tags: ios, react-native, webassembly

Here is my code

```
var bin = new Uint8Array([0,97,115,109,1,0,0,0,1,6,1,96,1,127,1,127,3,2,1,0,5,3,1,0,1,7,8,1,4,116,101,115,116,0,0,10,16,1,14,0,32,0,65,1,54,2,0,32,0,40,2,0,11]);
var mod = new WebAssembly.Module(bin);
var inst = new WebAssembly.Instance(mod, {});
const result = inst.exports.test(4) !== 0
```

Run it in react native and get

```
Out of executable memory in function at index 0
```

Not a problem if you enable Debug JS Remotely, as it runs in Chrome v8 engine.

- iOS: 12.2
- React Native: 0.59.2
- JavascriptCore: unknown

Possible related to https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/6042

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I'm also working on webassembly with react native.

Comment: asm.js is a solution. But I use the native module/bridge at the end for performance.